# Use of Notify() in thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

The methods `wait()` and `notify()` of the Object class are used for inter thread communication. when `wait()` is called, the object used to synchronize gives up its lock, but when notify is called the lock is not released until the synchronized block completes.
 So, what is the use of  the `notify()` function? Even if it was not there, the synchronized block would complete and release the lock right?

Comment: How would you wake a waiting object?

Comment: The java docs pretty much describes it: "notify(): Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor."

Comment: a waiting thread can sometimes be re-activated without notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notify()` is responsible for waking the waiting threads ie. taking the thread from wait queue to run queue. That is the waiting thread can be scheduled by the scheduler.

Comment: To be more accurate the *term* used here should be `thread` instead of `process`

Comment: @KuldeepJain My bad, I m more used to linux where there is no much difference between a process and a thread. correcting my answer

Answer (score 2):

The threads which are waiting to take the lock on the object have to be notified that the object they desire to take the lock on is free now, which is what `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods do.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.Object.notify()` wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

[image]

This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:

- By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
- By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes
  on the object.
- For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method 
  of that class.